# Return array with XQuery in SOAPUI

Tags: xquery, soapui

I'm using the XQuery assertion in SOAPUI. My XML response is this:

```
<Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="10">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <BANK_ACCT_NAME>BOA</BANK_ACCT_NAME>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="2">
            <BANK_ACCT_NAME>CHASE</BANK_ACCT_NAME>
        </Row>
        <Row rowNumber="3">
            <BANK_ACCT_NAME>CITI</BANK_ACCT_NAME>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

My XQuery Match is this:

```
<r>
{
for $x in /Results/ResultSet/Row/BANK_ACCT_NAME
return data($x)
}
</r>
```

Which gives me this a result:

```
<r>BOA CHASE CITY</r>
```

I would like to return an array if possible, i.e.:

```
<r>[BOA, CHASE, CITY]</r>
```

Or return it as a string, i.e.:

```
"[BOA, CHASE, CITY]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it as string you can use

```
let $x := string-join((/Results/ResultSet/Row/BANK_ACCT_NAME), ' ')
return data($x) # or return $x
```

or just

```
let $x := (/Results/ResultSet/Row/BANK_ACCT_NAME)
return data($x)
```

Comment: Thank you.The first option got me close enough. Needed the commas and the brackets, so the final solution was:
let $x := string-join((/Results/ResultSet/Row/BANK_ACCT_NAME), ', ')
return <r>[{$x}]</r>